# Specific element permutation within an array of characters in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, permutation

How can I list all uppercase/lowercase permutations for any letter specified in a character array?
So, say I have an array of characters like so: ['h','e','l','l','o']
and I wanted print out possible combinations for say the letter 'l' so it would print out [hello,heLlo,heLLo,helLo].

This is what I have so far(the only problem is that I can print the permutations however I'm not able to print them inside the actual word. so my code prints [ll,lL,Ll,LL] instead of the example above.

my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Sample Word
    String word = "Tomorrow-Today";

    //Sample Letters for permutation
    String rule_char_set = "tw";


    ArrayList<Character> test1 = lettersFound(word, rule_char_set);

    printPermutations(test1);







}

public static void printPermutations(ArrayList<Character> arrayList) {
    char[] chars = new char[arrayList.size()];
    int charIterator = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<arrayList.size(); i++){
        chars[i] = arrayList.get(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0, n = (int) Math.pow(2, chars.length); i < n; i++) {
        char[] permutation = new char[chars.length];
        for (int j =0; j < chars.length; j++) {
            permutation[j] = (isBitSet(i, j)) ? Character.toUpperCase(chars[j]) : chars[j];
        }
        System.out.println(permutation);
    }
}

public static boolean isBitSet(int n, int offset) {
    return (n >> offset & 1) != 0;
}

public static ArrayList<Character> lettersFound(String word, String rule_char_set) {

    //Convert the two parameter strings to two character arrays
    char[] wordArray = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    char[] rule_char_setArray = rule_char_set.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

    //ArrayList to hold found characters;
    ArrayList<Character> found = new ArrayList<Character>();

    //Increments the found ArrayList that stores the existent values.
    int foundCounter = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < rule_char_setArray.length; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < wordArray.length; k++) {
            if (rule_char_setArray[i] == wordArray[k]) {
                found.add(foundCounter, rule_char_setArray[i]);
                foundCounter++;

            }
        }
    }
    //Convert to a HashSet to get rid of duplicates
    HashSet<Character> uniqueSet = new HashSet<>(found);

    //Convert back to an ArrayList(to be returned) after filtration of duplicates.
    ArrayList<Character> filtered = new ArrayList<>(uniqueSet);

    return filtered;
}

}
```

Comment: Edited by error? Now i only see some JS code and random chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sanket Makani answer is perfect.

I may offer a more objective approach of this problem.

As an input you have a string to modify, and characters, which should be replaced with the modified case ( upper or lower ).
As an output you will have all permutated strings.

I would create a structure which contains index, and possible values to change with:

```
class Change {
int index;
char values[];
}
```

We will need to make all possible combinations, so lets include field which will tell which character is currently used in to our structure, and add some methods:

```
class Change {
int index;
char values[];
int cur;

void reset() {cur=0;}
boolen isMax(){return cur==values.length-1;}
void next(){cur++;}
char getValue(){ return values[cur]; }
}
```

We will have a list or array of these classes then, which we will put in to a separate class

```
class Combination {
Change changes[];

  void reset() { for (Change c: changes) c.reset();}

  boolean next() {
   for ( int i=0; i<changes.length; i++)
      if ( changes[i].isMax())
         changes[i].reset(); // next change will be taken in cycle, with "next()"
      else {changes[i].next(); return true;}

   return false; // all changes are max
  }
}
```

So when you initialize your "Combination" class by your input data, you may use it in cycle then.

```
Combination c = new Combination();
.... // initialization here 
c.reset();
do {
 ... //  update and print your string
} while ( c.next()  );
```

The  initialization of "Combination" and using of values for updating the input string I leave after you :)

Answer (score 6):

You need to make few changes in your program. Your logic is perfect that you need to find first the `characters` to be changed in the given word. After finding them, find `powerset` of `characters` to print all the permutation but this will only print `permuatation` of the characters of `rule-char-set` which are present in the given word.

Few changes you need to make is that first find all the `indexes` of `word` which contains characters of `rule-char-set`. Then find all `subsets` of indexes stored in an `ArrayList` and then for each element of each of the subsets, make the `character` present on that `index` to uppercase letter which will give you all `permutation` you require.

Consider an example that `word = "Hello"` and `rule-char-set="hl"` Then here first you need to find all indexes of `h` and `l` in the String `word`.

So here indexes are `0,2,3`. Store it in `ArrayList` and then find its `powerset`.Then for each `subset` ,make the `character` present on that `index` to the `uppercase` letter.

```
Word[] = {'h','e','l','l','o'}
indexes =  0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4


index[]= { 0 , 2 ,3}  //Store the indexes of characters which are to be changed


BITSET      |       SUBSET      |       word

000         |         -         |       hello 
001         |        {3}        |       helLo 
010         |        {2}        |       heLlo 
011         |       {2,3}       |       heLLo 
100         |        {0}        |       Hello 
101         |       {0,3}       |       HelLo 
110         |       {0,2}       |       HeLlo 
111         |      {0,2,3}      |       HeLLo
```

**Code :**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Sample Word
        String word = "Tomorrow-Today";

        //Sample Letters for permutation
        String rule_char_set = "tw";


        ArrayList<Integer> test1 = lettersFound(word, rule_char_set); //To store the indexes of the characters

        printPermutations(word,test1);

    }

    public static void printPermutations(String word,ArrayList<Integer> arrayList) {
        char word_array[]=word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        int length=word_array.length;
        int index[]=new int[arrayList.size()];

        for(int i=0; i<arrayList.size(); i++){
            index[i] = arrayList.get(i);
        }

        for (int i = 0, n = (int) Math.pow(2, index.length); i < n; i++) {
            char[] permutation = new char[length];

            System.arraycopy(word_array,0,permutation,0,length);    

            //First copy the original array and change 
            //only those character whose indexes are present in subset

            for (int j =0; j < index.length; j++) {
                permutation[index[j]] = (isBitSet(i, j)) ? Character.toUpperCase(permutation[index[j]]) : permutation[index[j]];
            }
            System.out.println(permutation);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isBitSet(int n, int offset) {
        return (n >> offset & 1) != 0;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> lettersFound(String word, String rule_char_set) {

        //Convert the two parameter strings to two character arrays
        char[] wordArray = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        char[] rule_char_setArray = rule_char_set.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

        //ArrayList to hold found characters;
        ArrayList<Integer> found = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        //Increments the found ArrayList that stores the existent values.
        int foundCounter = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < rule_char_setArray.length; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < wordArray.length; k++) {
                if (rule_char_setArray[i] == wordArray[k]) {
                    found.add(foundCounter, k);       //Store the index of the character that matches
                    foundCounter++;

                }
            }
        }
        return found;
    }

}
```

**Output :**

```
tomorrow-today
Tomorrow-today
tomorrow-Today
Tomorrow-Today
tomorroW-today
TomorroW-today
tomorroW-Today
TomorroW-Today
```

Answer (score 1):

For the permutation case, I think recursion is the best fit in terms of readability, taking into account that maybe is not best in terms of performance.

My approach would be this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    generateCombinations("hello", "l", "");
}

public static void generateCombinations(String text, String changingLetters, String current) {
    if (0 == text.length()) {
        System.out.println(current);
        return;
    }
    String currentLetter = text.substring(0, 1);
    if (changingLetters.contains(currentLetter)) {
        generateCombinations(text.substring(1), changingLetters, current + currentLetter.toUpperCase());
    }
    generateCombinations(text.substring(1), changingLetters, current + currentLetter);
}
```

The output for the main execution will be:

```
heLLo
heLlo
helLo
hello
```